# Change function for binomial polynome so that it output reverse arrays

Tags: java

I have a method for binomial polynome, however I want it to output an array in a reverse order. I can reverse arrays after the method, but that isn't very effective.

Can you help me?

```
public double[] binomialPolynome(int i, int j) {
    int power = 0;
    if (maxPower[i] < j) {
        power = maxPower[i];
    } else {
        power = j;
    }
    double[] result = new double[power + 1];
    for (int k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
        result[k] = factorial(power) / (factorial(k) * factorial(power - k))
                * Math.pow(-xPoints[i], k);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate the `result` array from right to left, rather than left to right.

```
result[k] = factorial(power) / (factorial(k) * factorial(power - k))
                * Math.pow(-xPoints[i], k);
```

Becomes:

```
result[result.length-1-k] = factorial(power) / (factorial(k) * factorial(power - k))
                * Math.pow(-xPoints[i], k);
```

or even just

```
result[power-k] = factorial(power) / (factorial(k) * factorial(power - k))
                * Math.pow(-xPoints[i], k);
```

Since `result.length = power+1`

Answer (score 1):

If you can consider substituting `double[]` for `Double []`, you can easily achieve this by:

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(result)); 
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(result));
```

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that rewriting the method in order to produce an array in reverse would be much more effective than just reversing the array afterwards.That's why I want to rewrite the method.